# How to top align a div inside another div

Tags: css

[image]

Hi

I want to place the div2 top align with the div1's border

So far I have tried this for div 2 but it did not work out well

```
element.style {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

this did not align the div at top position , what could be the fix to make it top aligned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would achieve this using `position: absolute;` on the child like said before, but instead of adding an additional div to the DOM to simulate use the space , I would use a **pseudo-element** (more precisely, the [::before pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)).

This is the structure I used for it:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">

    </div>
    <h1>Start</h1>
</div>
```

The div with class **parent** needs to be `position: relative;`, and the child needs to be absolute to it and set to be `top: 0;` like the following lines explain:

```
.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

You will though need to set this element a fixed height and width, otherwise it will not work.

The problem of this approach is that you will have a div that will be over the first 100px of your `.parent` div.

To solve this we need to create a pseudo-element on the `.parent` div that will simulate that space and make everything work better:

```
.parent:before {
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Here's a working fiddle with a sample code, hope this helps you!

http://jsfiddle.net/m54rxwjv/2/

PS: This will only work if you know that the **height** will always be 100px.

Comment: i tried and this should work also for parent with position:fixed

Answer (score 3):

Give position relative to your parent div and position absolute to inner div. Don't forget to set top:0px for inner div and after this your inner div will be always at the top of your parent div.

```
#div1{position:relative;}
#div2{position:absolute;top:0px;}
```

Comment: it works but the div 2 jumps out from the div 1 , thats the only issue , Thank you

Comment: Please create code snippet on any fiddle and post your link.

Answer (score 1):

As per Vipul's answer, I have create code snipped on jsfiddle for same behaviour:

http://jsfiddle.net/zo6jdp4b/1/

I have put one extra div on the top also so that one do not have any issue in child Div css:

```
.childDiv{
border: 1px solid blue;
height: 10px;
width: 30px;
position:absolute;
top: 0px;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Set your top div inside another div with sticky.
Like:

```
.div2 {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
}
```

It should be placed as your div2 in your div1 element in which you have (for example) overflow-y: scroll on a set height (and bellow content to be vertically scrolled).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.div1{
box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 150px;     
  width: 30px;
}
.div2{
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 3px solid green;
margin: -3px;
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
<div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice, but it will not work if you want to set inner div at bottom or right. So it is good for this case only but not standard for all case.

Answer (score 0):

```
.div1{
box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
position:relative;
}

.div2{
box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

div2 always at the top